# Variety whose secant variety is a cubic hypersurface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is there a characterization of projective varieties $X\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ whose secant variety is a hypersurface of degree $3$?

In the case that the secant variety does not have the expected dimension $2\dim(X)+1$, then these are exactly the Severi varieties which are characterized. But there are more examples like for instance the rational normal curve of degree $4$. Is there a complete classification?

Comment: The rational normal curve is a hyperplane section of the Veronese surface, which is a Severi variety.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Any thoughts on whether every such variety is the intersection of Severi variety with a linear space?